# Tkinter calling functions within a class

Tags: function, tkinter, command

Hi I am having trouble calling functions in tkinter

Here is the code

```
class Demo(tk.Frame):
    def ShowOption(self):
        print(self.v1.get())

    def __init__(self,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,width=800, height=600)
        f = Frame(self)

        optionList = ('A', 'B','C')
        self.v1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.v1.set(optionList[0])
        
        Opt1 = tk.OptionMenu(f, self.v1, *optionList,command = self.ShowOption)
        Opt1.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky='w')

        f.place(relx = 0.5,rely=0.5,anchor='c')
```

The problem I have is if I use this method it states the function takes 1 postional argument and none were given but if I use

```
        Opt1 = tk.OptionMenu(f, self.v1, *optionList,command = self.ShowOption() )
```

The function runs straight away when the class is created.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Callback for the `command` option of `OptionMenu` expects an argument which is the selected item.

So either you use `lambda` to skip the argument:

```
command=lambda v: self.ShowOption()
```

Or redefine `ShowOption()` to accept an argument:

```
def ShowOption(self, value):
    ...
```

Comment: Can I know the necessity of positional argument v

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
command = lambda : self.ShowOption()
```

Comment: This answer would be improved with further explanation: what the problem was in the original code, how this solves it.